# Switch the screen mode with MonkeyRunner?

Tags: android, python, monkeyrunner, monkey

How can I use MonkeyRunner to switch the screen mode(Portrait mode and Landscape mode)?

Comment: is the device that you are connected to an emulator or a physical device?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such way.

Answer (score 1):

There is a indirect way,you can toggle between portrain & landscape, but only the setting page.Steps:-

> 1.Disable auto-rotate screen option in settings page,keep the same page open.
>   2.Keep device in horizontally(It wont go to landscape mode as auto rotate is disabled
>   3.Get coordinates of disable/enable by enabling 'show pointer location'
>   4.touch the cordinates using monkeyrunner-it will goto landscape,touch again it will goback to portrait.

Answer (score 0):

If its a physical device then I do not know of a way to change the screen mode without actually physically putting the device on its side.