# monkeyrunner to rotate screen in real device / or service can do it

Tags: android, testing, monkeyrunner

Can monkeyrunner achieve the screen rotation by entering flip command?
If you know why, please teach me.

The other way should be a service to rotate the screen.
Will this be implementable?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Switch the screen mode with MonkeyRunner?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6741863/switch-the-screen-mode-with-monkeyrunner)

Comment: This can not be done. I've managed to get monkeyrunner to lock screen rotation by tapping on the settings, but that's as far as that goes.